# Cannot alter jQuery object variable. Is this a scope issue?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple script to move a sprite around the screen with the arrow keys. I want to contain a reference to my `$('#sprite')` in a variable called `$s`. But depending on where I declare and initialize `$s`, I get either a working function or a non working function. Why is this?

Edit: The difference is where I declare and initialize `$s`. I accidentally put the same code snippet in twice, but that's fixed now.

This does not work:

```html
$(document).ready(main());

function main(){
 
 var $s = $("#sprite");
 var time = 'fast';
 
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
//   var $s = $("#sprite");
   console.log($s);
   key = e.which
   switch(key){
    case 37: //left
     $s.animate({left: "-=10px"}, time);
     console.log("left");
     break;
    case 38: //up
     $s.animate({top: "-=10px"}, time)
     console.log("up");
     break;
    case 39: //right
     $s.animate({left: "+=10px"}, time)
     console.log("right");
     break;
    case 40: //down
     $s.animate({top: "+=10px"}, time)
     console.log("down");
     break;
    default:
     break;
   }
   
 });
};
```

This works:

```html
$(document).ready(main());

function main(){
 
// var $s = $("#sprite");
 var time = 'fast';
 
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
   var $s = $("#sprite");
   console.log($s);
   key = e.which
   switch(key){
    case 37: //left
     $s.animate({left: "-=10px"}, time);
     console.log("left");
     break;
    case 38: //up
     $s.animate({top: "-=10px"}, time)
     console.log("up");
     break;
    case 39: //right
     $s.animate({left: "+=10px"}, time)
     console.log("right");
     break;
    case 40: //down
     $s.animate({top: "+=10px"}, time)
     console.log("down");
     break;
    default:
     break;
   }
   
 });
};
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two?

Comment: You are calling `main` immediately. Pass the reference to `.ready()`, e.g., `.ready(main)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is whether you declare `$s` inside the keydown handler or outside? Let's look at what's happening, from the start:

```
$(document).ready(main());
```

You are CALLING the function `main`, and passing its *return value* to `$(document).ready()`. This is not what you want to do. Here, `main` gets executed immediately. What you want is:

```
$(document).ready(main);
```

without parentheses, just passing a *reference* to the function.

Why does it matter?

When you call the function immediately, the DOM isn't ready yet, and then `$s` has no value if it is defined in the outer function. But when you set it in the inner function, `$s` doesn't get set until you press a key, and by then the element exists.

So really, either one should work. The problem is in that other line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Both the codes are same.

Change the first line though..

```
// $(document).ready( main() );
   $(document).ready( main );
```